# Regex to match not more then a specific number of upper case characters

Tags: regex

How can I create a regular expression to check that there are not more then `n` capital letters in a string i.e.

if `n=3` then

```
aAnnBccD#!
AAbbC
```

should match, while

```
AbCdeFgHiJ
```

should fail.

Please advise on the same.

Comment: where's the code? And what's the language you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to check, example with [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!(?:.*?[A-Z]){4})
```

This fails at strings that contain `{4}` (more than 3) ...A-Z

[see test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wV8tH1/2)

Answer (score 2):

Just try with following regex:

```
^[^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*){0,3}$
```

Comment: @nhahtdh Right, fixed

Comment: @nhahtdh Even if {,3} is invalid. {0,3} should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^([^A-Z\n]*[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*){0,3}$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jM6oY3/2)

Comment: Do note that there are unnecessary backtracking due to `[^A-Z\n]*[^A-Z\n]*` expansion of the repeated group.